# How to optimize multiple self-JOINs?

Tags: mysql, database-design, join

I'm looking for advice on either optimizing multiple self-joins, or a better table/DB design.

One of the tables looks as follows (relevant cols only):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CountryData (
  countryDataID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  dataID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES DataSources (dataID),
  dataCode VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  countryID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Countries (countryID),
  year INT NOT NULL ,
  data DEC(20,4) NULL,
  INDEX countryDataYear (dataID, countryID, year));
```

The `data` column has values for a few hundred indicators, 90 countries, and 30 years for ~1mn rows total. A standard query requires selecting N indicators for a particular year and C countries, yielding a CxN table for 90 rows max.

With all values in a single column, self-joins seemed like the way to go. So I have experimented with various suggestions to speed those up, including indexing and creating new (temp) tables. At 9 self-joins, the query takes a little under 1 min. Beyond that, it spins forever.

The new table from where the self-joins take place has only about 1,000 rows, indexed on what seem to be the relevant variables - creation takes about 0.5 sec:

```
CREATE TABLE Growth
    SELECT dataID, countryID, year, data
    FROM CountryData
    WHERE dataID > 522 AND year = 2017;

CREATE INDEX growth_ix 
    ON Growth (dataID, countryID);
```

The `SELECT` query then arranges up to XX indicators in the results table, with XX unfortunately <10:

```
SELECT 
    Countries.countryName AS Country,   
    em01.em,
    em02.em,
    em03.em
    ...
    emX.em
FROM    
    (SELECT
        em1.data AS em,
        em1.countryID
    FROM Growth AS em1
    WHERE
    em1.dataID = 523) as em01
    JOIN 
    (SELECT
        em2.data AS em,
        em2.countryID
    FROM Growth AS em2
    WHERE
    em2.dataID = 524) as em02
    USING (countryID)
    JOIN
    (SELECT
        em3.data AS em,
        em3.countryID
    FROM Growth AS em3
    WHERE
    em3.dataID = 525) as em03
    USING (countryID)
    ...
    JOIN
    (SELECT
        emX.data AS em,
        emX.countryID
    FROM Growth AS em5
    WHERE
    emX.dataID = 527) as emXX
    USING (countryID)
    JOIN Countries 
    USING (countryID)
```

I'd actually like to retrieve a few more variables, plus potentially join other tables. Now I'm wondering whether there's a way to run this more efficiently, or whether I should take an altogether different approach, such as using wide tables with indicators in different columns to avoid self-joins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a need for denormalizing the table. Self-joining will work fine if you have indexes that will be used effectively. For the specific query, I'd add an index on `(year, dataID, countryID, data)` and not use any derived tables:

```
SELECT 
    c.countryName AS Country,   
    em01.data AS data01,
    em02.data AS data02,
    ...
    emXX.data AS dataXX
FROM  
    Countries AS c
      JOIN CountryData AS em01
        ON  em01.year = 2017
        AND em01.dataID = 523 
        AND em01.countryID = c.countryID 
      JOIN CountryData AS em02
        ON  em02.year = 2017
        AND em02.dataID = 524
        AND em02.countryID = c.countryID
      ... 
      JOIN CountryData AS emXX
        ON  emXX.year = 2017
        AND emXX.dataID = YYY
        AND emXX.countryID = c.countryID 
 ;
```

The only issue you'll have is that MySQL has a hard limit of maximum 61 joins in a query. So, you won't be able to have 90 columns with the above query.

Another observation is that you don't seem to need any aggregated data but just a tiny subset of the (small or big table, doesn't matter). With the suggested index, you could just write a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    cd.countryID,
    c.countryName AS Country,   
    cd.dataID,
    cd.data
FROM  
    Countries AS c
      JOIN CountryData AS cd
        ON  cd.countryID = c.countryID 
WHERE 
      cd.year = 2017
  AND cd.dataID IN (522, 523, ..., YYY) 
ORDER BY
    cd.countryID,
    cd.dataID ;
```

and have the pivot transformation done in your application.

Comment: Great, thank you very much, this is not only fast @ 0.269 and 0.042 sec for the first and second query, respectively. It's also a lot simpler, and quite illustrative on how to do this properly. Will vote up once I've worked my way up to 15 reputation :)

Comment: I have a very similar situation regarding a large amount of self-joins, and this response is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Thnx @BMB . Where is the heptagon sign in your profile from?